# Why should i use Attributes instead of implementing an interface?

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection, interface, attributes

Why do you use an attribute instead of inheriting from an interface? 
Wouldn’t that be easier implement an interface than adding a whole new concept to C#(attributes)?

Atribute Example:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyObject {
  public int n1 = 0;
  public int n2 = 0;
  public String str = null;
}
```

Interface Example:

```
public class MyObject: ISerializable {
  public byte[] getBinaryData() { // some code }
  public int n1 = 0;
  public int n2 = 0;
  public String str = null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is not covering all functionality that attributes provide. Using `interface`s you cannot express additional information about a class or a method. You will need to use attributes for it.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw(v=vs.110).aspx)

> •Attributes add metadata to your program. Metadata is information about the types defined in a program. All .NET assemblies contain a specified set of metadata that describes the types and type members defined in the assembly. You can add custom attributes to specify any additional information that is required.
>
> •You can apply one or more attributes to entire assemblies, modules, or smaller program elements such as classes and properties.
>
> •Attributes can accept arguments in the same way as methods and properties.
>
> •Your program can examine its own metadata or the metadata in other programs by using reflection.

Comment: The second bullet is an important one to emphasize - it's a *consistent* way to apply markers at all kinds of levels, rather than, say, Marker Interfaces, which could only be applied at the class/interface level.